# Whn a Weighted Sobolev space is Hilbert?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces, elliptic-operators

Consider $V : \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let
$$X(\mathbb{R}^N) = \left\{ u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N) : \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} Vu^2 < +\infty \right\}.$$
Also consider the application
$$
||u|| = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u|^2 + \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} Vu^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
Under what conditions on $V$, the space $(X(\mathbb{R}^N), ||\cdot||)$ is a Banach space?

Any reference with this subject would be very useful for me.

Comment: I think you need a condition to ensure that all functions with finite $X$-norm are actually in $H^1$. Otherwise one could construct a sequence in $X$ converging to a function outside of $H^1$ with finite $X$-norm.

Comment: For exemple, $V(x) \geq \alpha > 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^N$? I think this makes $X(\mathbb{R}^N) \subset H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. This is enough to conclude that $X(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is complete?